# Change horizontal alignment of cell text in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, alignment

I have a table that fits to the width of my page using the `X`-coloum type:

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |} 
    \hline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis \\
    \hline
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The cells are aligned in blocks:

[image: Cells aligned in blocks]

Is there a way to align them differently without typing out e.g. `\raggedright` before every cell? The `l`-coloumn type messes up the table's width:

[image: Coloumns overflowing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is make a new type of column for `tabularx`, said `Z`:

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

But the easiest way is use `tabulary` instead of `tabularx` and `L`,`R`,`C` or `J` columns

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LRCJ}\toprule 
\lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][1-2] & 
\lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][1-2]  \\\midrule   
\lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][1-2] & 
\lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][1-2]  \\\bottomrule   
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But note that is not just the only difference between both packages:

Whatever the contents, `tabularx` will use all the `\textwitdh` to  make all `X` columns of the same width, while `tabulary` will try to optimize the width of each column according to the content, taking the available horizontal space only if needed. For instance, if you type only "Foo" in one column, `tabulary` will make a narrow column while leaving more space for the others, but if the content of the others is not enough, also the table   will be narrower that `\textwidth`. Also worth to mention that with very uneven columns, the columns with less text could be too narrow, with excessive line breaks, in order to fit the table in a  minimal vertical space, but you can  use `\tymin` and `\tymax` to control that, as explained in the manual.

If this is not an advantage but a drawback for you, use the first solution.

Comment: the "don't stretch tables" feature of tabulary is easily avoided (there are some answers on site) I think it just never ocurred to me that anyone would want to do that:-)  but you didn't mention the main difference, all X columns are the same width but each column in tabulary is set to a width guessed from the size of the content of the cells. You don't see that here as each cell has exactly the same content.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, forget to mention the different widths of columns, although  in fact  I tend to use  `tabulary` instead of `tabularx` mainly because of that, as well as the  possibility to influence in the guessed width with `\tymin` and `\tymax`.